# C# How to check if a number is any of the group values?

Tags: c#, python, arrays, find, contains

I'm trying to convert a python script to C# and i'm trying to make sure it's in 1 line of code.

How would I go about converting this line?

```
if op.scale in (2, 4, 8):
```

yeah op.scale is a integer datatype so it's checking if it matches any of those values in the array.

I know in C# you can use Range but this isn't a range question

```
if (Enumerable.Range(2,8).Contains(op.scale))
```

A attempt I just tried.. looks promising but I got to get it to compile.

```
if(Array.Exists(new Integer() {2,4,8}, element => element == op.scale))
```

Comment: if(new[]{2,4,8}.Contains(op.scale))?

Comment: looks good thanks sorry if the question is too simple I got a mental block

Comment: "string in array" covers this case as well. Answers include several generic variants that work with any types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an array:

```
 if (new[] {2, 4, 8}.Contains(op.scale))
```

Comment: thanks worked i'll accept this as the answer in 10 mins.

Comment: nice - (could not find duplicate for int, marked as duplicate of same question for strings... feel free to re-open if you think answers in string case don't cover this).

Comment: It's all good maybe that linked resource will help out people get a better understanding for other cases.. Hack in the future stackoverflow will be the ultimate database for autonomous programming AI the more connections made today the better in the future haha